# Should questions be deleted/closed when the issue was only a typo?

Tags: discussion

I answered recently the question '[Adjusting pdflatex settings](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20593/adjusting-pdflatex-settings)'.

The OP had misspelled a variable of the plugin vim-latex which therefore did not change the behavior of the plugin.

At first I wanted to add my suspicion only as a comment, then I decided to add it as answer so the OP can mark it as answered if the typo was the problem. Also others can see early on that the question has been answered.

I have two questions:

1. How should one respond to those questions where a typo is very likely the reason for the question? comment or answer

I was wondering whether this question and its answer has a real value in the long run.

2. Should those questions be marked for deletion or should I open a close vote after the OP has confirmed that the typo was the problem?

   Of course, the site response should not discourage new users to ask questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the close votes, when you select the "off topic" option, you have a sub option saying:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

So, once it is clear that the problem comes from a typo (as it is now that your answer has been accepted, or after a simple comment confirming it) the right way to go is to open a close vote. We don't need to delete the question but we don't need to keep it open neither.

(In the case of the question you linked, I just closed it)